# Looking for a suffix that is opposite of "-prone", but softer than "-proof"

Tags: single-word-requests

Say I'm talking about a car that has less of a tendency to crash than other cars.  It is the opposite of a "crash-prone" car.  But it isn't "crash-proof" either, in that you can crash it if you try hard enough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about just crash-**resistant**?

Comment: +1 That's what watchmakers do...they pull up short of saying their watches are *water-proof* and instead call them *water-resistant*.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  I feel kind of dumb now for not thinking of that....it felt like it was on the tip of my tongue!

Comment: @JLG That's like Titanic: many people thought it to be sinking-proof, while it was in fact sinking-resistant.

Comment: @Malcom, From some accounts of that dreadful night, it wasn't even sink-resistant, let alone unsinkable.

Answer (score 5):

both "-proof" and "-resistant" have connotations of being able to withstand a crash without taking as much damage as might be expected rather than being less likely to get into a crash in the first place, so I'll suggest "-avoidant".  Although I'd probably recommend using it as in

> The car has good crash-avoidance capabilities

because saying "the car is crash-avoidant" just sounds funny to me.

Comment: Sounds like a car that can drive by itself, avoiding crashes.

Comment: @annawie: [those exist](http://www.iihs.org/research/qanda/crash_avoidance.html)

Comment: Or *-averse*. Though both that and *-avoidant* suggest that the car has agency.